# Am I on the right track in designing a winforms app that will call a WCF service?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a c# winforms app. My app is going to validate addresses through the Address Look up Web tool provided by the USPS. The address is sent using xml through an HTTP request and the cleaned address is returned to the app.

I am thinking that i will create an WCF app that will communicate with the USPS. My winforms app will have a service reference to the WCF app. I will pull the data from the address fields on the dialog box after they are entered by the user and bundle them into an address object. I will pass the address object to the WCF app. The WCF app will unbundle the address fields and place them in XML format. Then the WCF app will send an HTTP request to the USPS passing over the XML. A response will be received i will parse the XML returned and bundle it into an address object which will be returned to the cient app and displayed in the address fields.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Why not call the USPS service directly?

Comment: Personally, I'd say you're adding an unnecessary layer of complexity. Why not just have your application call the USPS service directly? Also, the USPS webservice will allow you to pass through an object without you having to build the XML (much the same as a WCF service)

Comment: no the USPS requires the data to be passed in XML format as a part of the http request.